What killed my USB SSD Drive?
I got a new USB 2T Samsung SSD drive back at Thanksgiving to replace another drive that was starting to go bad. I then copied as much as I could from the drive.
About 6 months later, I needed some files that I thought I copied earlier, so I decided to copy them from an older computer. I unplugged the drive my computer while it was hibernating. This is a Windows 10 computer.
I plugged the drive into an older Windows 7 computer and copied some folder from there onto the drive. I then shut down the computer and plugged the drive back into my still-hibernating Windows 10 computer.
A few hours later, I turned on my computer, went to the folder I had just copied, and Windows said the folder was corrupted. Oh, well, at least it's on my older computer if I need it. I then clicked on another folder and Windows said that folder was corrupted also!
I then shut down my computer completely, unplugged the drive, and plugged it into a Windows 11 laptop. Windows labeled this "Drive D" instead of my label, "SamsungD". I clicked on the drive and it said "This drive is not formatted. Would you like to format it now?" I clicked no, then Safely Eject Hardware.
I unplugged the drive and plugged it into my Windows 7 laptop. But the same thing: Windows labeled this "Drive D" also. And when I clicked on the drive, it also said "This drive is not formatted. Would you like to format it now?"
I opened a command prompt and ran "chkdsk". It ran very quickly but it said there were issues in the master file table and to run with the "F" flag, so I did. It said no bad sectors. I restarted the computer, but the same thing: Windows labeled it as "Drive D" and "This drive is not formatted".
I had been using the drive for about 6 months and I bought it brand-new at Amazon. I had about 1.2T of data on it, ranging from family photos to digital models, to backups of files and games. I also used it as the download folder for eMule.
So what killed the drive and what should I not do in the future?

Did running eMule "burn out" something?
Should I never unplug a drive when the computer is hibernating?
The USB port go bad?
Or did I just get unlucky and it's a bad drive?


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Should I never unplug a drive when the computer is hibernating? It's more complicated than that. Using it with Windows 7 after being hibernated in a modern OS was likely what "killed" it. Error correcting when the contents were still accessible but corrupt would have probably saved the data. Now it's anyone's guess. The physical drive should be fine though if formatted again.

It's hard to say what happened now, but I can offer a conjecture.  Here's a likely scenario:
Your host computer had some cached changes in RAM that had not been committed to the drive when you hibernated.  Note hibernation does not always flush those changes back to media, the intent after all is to rapidly enter and leave low-power mode.  What happened then is you pulled the drive and plugged it into a different system, and made changes to the drive while there were still pending writes waiting on the hibernating computer.
Now there are a few paths that could have happened here, but reintroducing the now altered drive to the hibernating computer was basically what did it.  The drive now no longer matches what the hibernating computer believes to be present, so when it wakes up... well, Bad Things happened.  Likely old data was written over the new data, and since data at the lowest level is stored in fixed-size erase blocks and files cross boundaries, you wound up with some critical information getting destroyed.
Good news is the drive is probably physically fine, but its data is very likely easier to declare lost and reformat than it is to recover.

Hi Nerf42, welcome to superuser. Well written answer! I could not describe it better. No novels, short and precise. Well done!

This is what I suspected might have happened so thanks for the confirmation. :)
